# Pass only non None values as argument to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop that returns a value or None depending on field being selected.

**For Loop:**

```
for fieldname, value in form.data.items():
    if value is not None:
        print(value)
```

Given below is the output of the print statement of the *for loop*:

```
store_name
None
store_location
None
```

I am trying to pass the output of the above loop statement to a function as shown below:

```
output = store_details() <<-- arguments to this function to only include non None items obtained from the above for loop statement
```

In the above example only `store_name` and `store_location` should be passes as arguments. How could I pass only the **non None** items as arguments? Please note the list arguments could vary each time hence I am trying to build this function such that the store_details function only passes non None values each time.

Update:

Given below is the loop I am trying to execute. This works fine if all the fields are selected (There are 5 fields in the page from which the user can select).

```
l = []
    for fieldname, value in form.data.items():
        if value is not None:
            l.append(value)
print(l)

p = l[:-1]

output = store_details(*p)
```

If any of the fields are not selected, it returns a 'None' which throws

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist in table
```

Comment: What does form.data.items() return?

Comment: @Rarblack, given below is what gets printed if I select a few fields.

dict_items([('store_name', 'None'), ('store_type', 'store_type'), ('store_location', 'store_location'), ('csrf_token', 'ImI0MzQyYzcwZDk5NTVmMGQxMWY5YTk3NDhmNTNkNzJmMjQ5NWIzZTIi.Dtllqg.-SXYDYkBmQiPjSmo01VnDgSbZrE')])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use list-comprehension:

You can do either:

```
output = store_details([value for fieldname, value in form.data.items() if not value == None])
```

or (you can do form.data.values() to to retrieve only values of dictionary)

```
output = store_details([value for value in form.data.values() if not value == None])
```

And you can also store the value of list-comprehension and pass it:

```
l = [value for value in form.data.values() if not value == None]
output = store_details(l)
```

**EDIT :** The error is because None has been written as a string in value, not an object None therefore if clause not catching it.

```
>>> a= dict([('store_name', 'None'), ('store_type', 'store_type'), ('store_location', 'store_location'), ('csrf_token', 'ImI0MzQyYzcwZDk5NTVmMGQxMWY5YTk3NDhmNTNkNzJmMjQ5NWIzZTIi.Dtllqg.-SXYDYkBmQiPjSmo01VnDgSbZrE')])
>>> del a['csrf_token']
>>> a
{'store_name': 'None', 'store_type': 'store_type', 'store_location': 'store_location'}
>>> [i for i in a.values() if not i == 'None']
['store_type', 'store_location']
>>>
```

If you prefer of using your own code make this change:

```
l = []
a = form.data
del a['csrf_token'] # token field is removed

    for fieldname, value in a.items():
        if value is not 'None':
            l.append(value)
print(l)

output = store_details(*l)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I get the below error:

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "]"
LINE 1: select [] from table_name

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your full code or where error occurs it is hard to say like this

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried with your modified code and find that if all fields are selected it works fine.. However if one of the fields are not selected, it throws an error "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist in table".. Could you please assist on this.. Thnx.

Comment: Try it without deleting hte csrf column

Comment: it returns a list ['None', 'store_type', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'ImI0MzQyYzcwZDk5NTVmMGQxMWY5YTk3NDhmNTNkNzJmMjQ5NWIzZTIi.Dtl_hw.DfRbLFmI8JQ-kU56Z1wq1lPK514'] when i do print(a).. Later throws an error column does not exist in the table..

Comment: Hey look the part you have to ask for help in your question is correct but I don't know what you are doing in strore_details method and this is a totally different question.

Comment: I am basically passing in the columns selected in store_details and passing it to a query "cursor.execute('select {} from table'.format(', '.join(str(field) for field in field_names)))"

Comment: If I select all of the columns it extract the output.. But if I only select a few columns from that list, it says column 'none' does not exist in table..

Comment: This is because it fill your input value with none dict element till size match

Comment: Please accept an answer to close the question and if you need further help do not hesitate of asking another question

Comment: could you advice on how to overcome this problem of skipping the None column before passing it to the query

Comment: You should open another question and please post the code inside of story_details method othervise I am just guessing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways actually. One is a dictionary comprehension:

```
fields = {field:value for field,value in form.data.items() if value != None and value != 'None' and field != 'csrf_token'}
output = store_details(**fields)
```

**UPDATE**
I've included the 'None' check and excluded the csrf_token. Please use `and` operator, not the `or`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I encountered an issue where in both the key and value pair are returned as below.

{'store_name' : 'store_name' , 'store_id' : 'None', 'store_location' : 'store_location' , 'store_address' : 'None', 'csrf_token' : 'feferf'}

how could I only return the value alone and exclude all None

Comment: also could you please advice how I could also not pass in the last key value - pair ('csrf_token' : 'feferf')

Comment: I have modified as per your latest code and I get the error

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "csrf_token" does not exist in table...

Comment: I've updated the response with the correct code for the conditional. Check it ;)

Comment: thanks for the update, tried with the modified code.. It throws an error saying -- "TypeError: store_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'store_id'" .. store_id is the first column my list

Comment: Can you post the definition of store_details()?